# Java "Thread-2" without stack prevents termination

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging, stack-trace

I have a pretty complex java program, which doesn't terminate.
The eclipse debugger is showing a thread that can be suspended, but has no stack trace.
It is called "Thread-2".

The `jstack -l` output for this thread is:

```
"Thread-2" #17 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1268002800 nid=0x3342 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

I added a breakpoint to Thread.start(), but I cannot find a thread called "Thread-2".
The thread just appears after the two "AWT-Event-Queue" threads were created.
I don't create any threads manually in my program.

After the main thread and all other threads exit, and the JFrame is disposed, the following threads still exist:

```
Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Running) 
Thread [Thread-2] (Running) 
Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)
```

When suspending the VM, the following threads exist:

```
Daemon System Thread [Signal Dispatcher] (Suspended)    
Daemon System Thread [Finalizer] (Suspended)    
Daemon System Thread [Reference Handler] (Suspended)    
Daemon System Thread [Java2D Disposer] (Suspended)  
Daemon System Thread [AWT-XAWT] (Suspended) 
Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Suspended)   
Thread [Thread-2] (Suspended)   
Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Suspended)
```

How can I get more information about this thread, or allow it to terminate?

**EDIT 1:**

According to the `Dependency Hierarchy` of the eclipse `pom.xml` view, I use the following third party libraries:

```
guava 17.0 [compile]
hamcrest-core 1.3 [test]
junit 4.11 [test]
log4j-api 2.0-beta9 [compile]
log4j-core 2.0-beta9 [compile]
```

**EDIT 2:**

Adding breakpoints to all constructors of the thread class, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35128213/577485, I see that `Thread-0` and `Thread-1` are created by `log4j`, but not `Thread-2`. It still just appears as before and no breakpoint triggers when it is constructed.

**EDIT 3:**

Now it's getting creepy. Not even the `stop()` method works, when invoked on the thread. I added it to the code given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35128149/577485.
At least `System.exit(int)` still works. But as said in a comment, I don't want to use that.

**EDIT 4:**

Info about my system:

- I'm running the newest stable version of Ubuntu 15.10 Wily. I have the `security`, `updates` and `backports` repos enabled.
- My JVM version is:

`java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)`

**EDIT 5:**

I executed the program with Java version `jre-8u71-linux-x64` directly downloaded from java.com, but the error persists. `jstack -l` shows the same strange thread. Note that the program was still built with the older java version. *Edit:* After compiling it with java8u72 from oracle.com, I get the same behaviour.

**EDIT 6:**

I iterated over all the threads fields, here's the output. I cannot get any hint out of those fields, the thread doesn't even have a target.

```
name: [C@6b67034
priority: 5
threadQ: null
eetop: 140274638530560
single_step: false
daemon: false
stillborn: false
target: null
group: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
contextClassLoader: null
inheritedAccessControlContext: java.security.AccessControlContext@0
threadInitNumber: 3
threadLocals: null
inheritableThreadLocals: null
stackSize: 0
nativeParkEventPointer: 0
tid: 17
threadSeqNumber: 20
threadStatus: 5
parkBlocker: null
blocker: null
blockerLock: java.lang.Object@16267862
MIN_PRIORITY: 1
NORM_PRIORITY: 5
MAX_PRIORITY: 10
EMPTY_STACK_TRACE: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@453da22c
SUBCLASS_IMPLEMENTATION_PERMISSION: ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "enableContextClassLoaderOverride")
uncaughtExceptionHandler: null
defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler: null
threadLocalRandomSeed: 0
threadLocalRandomProbe: 0
threadLocalRandomSecondarySeed: 0
```

**EDIT 7:**

Added a watchpoint to the `name` field of `Thread`. It is only accessed by my analytics code, and seems to be never written...

**EDIT 8:**

`jstack` -F -m throws an error for my program:

```
Attaching to process ID 10973, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.71-b15
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deduce type of thread from address 0x00007ff68000c000 (expected type JavaThread, CompilerThread, ServiceThread, JvmtiAgentThread, or SurrogateLockerThread)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:169)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.first(Threads.java:153)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PStack.initJFrameCache(PStack.java:200)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PStack.run(PStack.java:71)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PStack.run(PStack.java:58)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PStack.run(PStack.java:53)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:66)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.types.WrongTypeException: No suitable match    for type of address 0x00007ff68000c000
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.InstanceConstructor.newWrongTypeException(InstanceConstructor.java:62)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VirtualConstructor.instantiateWrapperFor(VirtualConstructor.java:80)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:165)
    ... 16 more
```

The class name of the strange thread is `java.lang.Thread`.

I don't use any command line arguments for executing the program. Adding the `-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true` option gives the strange thread the name `Thread-1`.

I updated `log4j` to 2.5, and the strange thread now has name `Thread-0`, when the `-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true` option is given, and `Thread-1`, when it isn't.

**EDIT 9:**

Completely removed log4j, error persists. The thread is now called `Thread-0`.

---

[Here](https://github.com/ISibboI/AgentSim/tree/fix_%2334_vm_not_shutting_down)'s the project, if that helps.

Comment: This seems like a third party library you use in your application creating a new Thread manually and it is not a Daemon thread but a user thread. What are the libraries you use?

Comment: @shazin Added info about the libraries.

Comment: I cloned the project and ran it straight from IntelliJ Idea on Oracle JDK 1.8u72, running on Mac OS X. The JVM terminated without problems when I closed the frame, both on the `master` and `fix_#34_vm_not_shutting_down` branches (which one should I use?). I could never see a `Thread-2` thread when the program was running. Which JVM and OS are you using? Can you try running on the latest JDK 8?

Comment: Added info about my current setup. I'll try running it with java8.
On `fix_#34_vm_not_shutting_down` I poked the thread with everything I could, to make it terminate. On `master`, I do nothing about that. So if it works on master, I'm very happy.

Comment: Can you include a thread dump including the call stack of the non-ending thread?  A gist of it is fine.

Comment: @JohnVint do you mean the stack trace? The thread seems to have none. See the jstack output. Is there more internal data I can get about a Thread?

Comment: @Sibbo jstack is fine.  Is there a link to the full dump/stack trace?

Comment: Oh, I see. It literally has no thread stack.

Comment: You can try and take a Java heap dump and investigate the thread stack there.  May give you new results.

Comment: One more suggestion for debugging. Put a debug break point in the Thread's init method where it assigns to name and the setName method. Then you can see where Thread-2 is being created (if ever). Can tell you more info about what's it's being used for and the runnable that it's executing

Comment: @JohnVint Thanks, tried that. Seems like it doesn't work :(

Comment: That is weird, when I run your code, I not only don't have `Thread-2` but also no `Thread-0` and `-1`. You said threads 0 and 1 are created by Log4J. I can see that Log4J creates a single-thread fixed thread pool executor in `o.a.l.log4j.core.jmx.Server#registerMBeans()`. But that would name the threads like `pool-x-thread-y`. Anyhow, if you set `-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true` for the JVM it should **not** create this executor. Can you try setting this property? Do you use any command-line java arguments for running?

Comment: Also, I've put a breakpoint on the `shutdown` and `shutdownNow` methods of `ThreadPoolExecutor` to check if Log4J is shutting it correctly and the breakpoints were never hit, so maybe that's indeed a culprit.

Comment: Plus, I'd suggest upgrading to the latest Log4J 2.5 - 2.0-beta9 is over 2 years old and, well.. beta ;)

Comment: Putting a debug on the Thread#setName or init methods don't stop the program?

Comment: try `jstack -F -m <pid>` instead, that should list native stacks too. also, instead of using breakpoints, why not just suspend the VM and inspect the thread with the debugger?

Comment: @JohnVint: It does, but not for the strange thread.

Comment: @AdamMichalik Thanks for the input. I followed your hints, and added the result to the question.

Comment: @the8472 I added the result of the command. It threw an error :(
Do you mean the eclipse debugger? It doesn't give me anything about the thread. It doesn't even have a stack trace.

Comment: I would suggest to exhaust the Log4J suspicion. One track is: replace Log4J with [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/)+[Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). You can do it just for testing following [these migration guidelines](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j) without going through all the places in your code where you use Log4J. Another track is: that thread *might be* a shutdown hook added in Log4J's `DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.addShutdownHook()`. Put a breakpoint in that method, check the name of the thread which is added as the hook and check what is the class of ThreadFactory.

Comment: @AdamMichalik Thanks for your input. I just completely removed all logging from the code and removed the dependency. The error persists :(

Comment: @Sibbo I think it's time to get the assembly printed out.

Comment: Are you getting this hang during the test run or also outside running the tests?  If it does not matter how you run you application.  I think that it might be caused but the guava library that you are using since this library has a collection of threading services that might be the cause of your issue.  Have you determined that none of the guava classes you use do not use threading calls?

Comment: @Sibbo For what it's worth I also tried running it and it shut down successfully.  You are likely having an environment related problem.  You should next try and print out the assembly so we can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: @JohnVint I'm currently doing a project for my university, I'll be back in a week or so.

Comment: Since I have to award the bounty today, I will give it to @StephenC. His answer was the most helpful until now.
Thanks to all the others that gave comments or answers, you helped a lot. I'm pretty sure right now, that the bug is not in my program, but caused by something else. After this week I will have time to look a little bit more into that.
I'll leave the accepted answer open, for the case that someone comes up with an explanation. If noone does and when my exam period starts, I will just give it to the most helpful answer until then.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why the breakpoint on `Thread.start()` did not work, but you could also try intercepting the thread >>creation<< by setting a breakpoint on the Thread constructors, or on the (internal) `Thread.init()` method.

The fact that the thread has the name `Thread-2` implies that it was created by one of the constructors that generates a default thread name.  That suggests that it was not created by the JVM or standard Java class libraries.  It also narrows down the constructors that could have been used to create it.

> How can I get more information about this thread ...

I can't think of any way apart from setting breakpoints.

> ... or allow it to terminate?

If you can find where it is created, you should be able to use `setDaemon(true)` to mark it as a daemon thread.  However, this needs to be done before the thread is started.

Another possibility would be to find the thread by traversing the `ThreadGroup` tree and then calling `Thread.interrupt()` on it.  ( `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` is another way of tracking down the thread object. ) However, there is no guarantee that the thread will "respect" the interrupt and shut down.

Finally, you could just call `System.exit(...)`.

---

**UPDATE**

I mentioned that the thread might not respect `interrupt()` and I'm not surprised that `stop()` doesn't work.  (It is deprecated, and may not even be implemented on some platforms.)

However, if you have managed to implement code that actually *finds* the mystery thread, you could dig around to find either the `Thread` subclass, or the `Runnable` that it is instantiated with.  If you can print out the fully qualified class name, that will give you a big clue as to where it comes from.  (Assuming that you are still having no success with breakpoints, then you may need to use "nasty" reflection to extract the runnable from the thread's private `target` field.)

Comment: Thanks for the info, it helped a lot already. I added an edit to the question explaining what happened. `System.exit()` Is not an option, as it will just shadow the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The target is null. Which is strange I guess. I added a list of all fields to the question.

Comment: That does not make sense.  If you called `Thread.start()` on a `java.lang.Thread` that has a `null` for its `Runnable` the thread should terminate immediately.  I wonder if you are seeing the results of some native / "unsafe" code trashing things ...

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm currently hunting a bug on a lower level. Especially because on a Mac, everything seems to be fine. My next idea is learning gdb, and using it to find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this enough for you, but the following code will allow you to try to `interrupt` any `Thread` by its name:

```
    //Set of current Threads
    Set<Thread> setOfThread = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();

    //Iterate over set to find yours
    for(Thread thread : setOfThread){
        if (thread.getName().equals("Thread-2")) {
            thread.interrupt();
            break;
        }
    }
```

---

Also, take a look on this [article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue226.html) from JavaSpecialists that tries to identify the creator of a Thread based on the fact that the constructor of `Thread` makes a call to the security manager. If we add a custom `SecurityManager` to our System, we may track the initiator of a Thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, interrupting changes nothing, the thread stays `RUNNABLE` and has still no stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should change your `_exit` flag to `volatile`, since it's read from one thread (your main method), and written by another (JCF/Swing event handler), so it's possible your main thread isn't getting a "fresh" value.  Specifically: the thread may be saving the field to a CPU register and not reloading it from memory as you're looping.  'volatile' will prevent that behavior:

`private volatile boolean _exit;`

However, based on your stack traces I don't think that's your problem, since we don't see your main method in there.  But this should be done anyway, it's just good practice.

Assuming that doesn't fix it, I'm guessing your problem is that you have at least one other Window (besides `AgentFrame`) that isn't being disposed.  The AWT thread won't stop until all Windows are disposed.

Put this at the end of your main method:

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Window.getWindows()))`

I'm guessing you're going to see more than just your `DrawFrame` there.  If I were to guess, I'd say `UISettingsFrame` is in there, undisposed.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Sadly, none of that helped. The windows are not displayable at the end of the main method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not displayable".  It's not enough that all your windows are hidden.  They must be *disposed*, or else the AWT thread will never end.  Try this at the end of your main: `for (Window w: Window.getWindows()) if (w.isValid()) throw new RuntimeException("Fix this");`.  If that exception throws, you need to ensure that window is getting disposed (in the window's own code, I don't recommend iterating & disposing in main, that would be a bit sloppy).

Comment: The windows are not valid either. Nevertheless I added disposing the settingsframe before it is nulled.